# Access to field information with a list of ids in a inner join

Tags: mysql, join

I created a table called `recommendations` that looks like this:

```
+----+---------------+---------------------+
| id | name          | elements_to_announce |
+----+---------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Recomanation1 | 2                   |
|  2 | Recomanation1 | 1,2                 |
+----+---------------+---------------------+
```

And another table called `products` that looks like that:

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | name              |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | Low fat croissant |
|  2 | Yupi bread        |
+----+-------------------+
```

Now I want to create a join with this two tables that gets the information of `recommendations` but replaces the `elements_to_announce` with the names of products.

It has to be something like this:

```
+----+---------------+---------------------------------------+
| id | name          | elements_to_announce                  |
+----+---------------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | Recomanation1 | Yupi bread                            |
|  2 | Recomanation1 | Low fat croissant,Yupi bread          |
+----+---------------+---------------------------------------+
```

I make a lot of tests and the code that works almost fine is that one:

```
SELECT
      r.id AS recommendation_id,
      GROUP_CONCAT(p.id) AS product_id
      FROM products AS p
      JOIN recommendations AS r
    GROUP BY r.id
```

The problem with this code is that it returns all product names.

**EDIT:**
The result of my "almost fine" query:

```
+----+---------------+---------------------------------------+
| id | name          | elements_to_announce                  |
+----+---------------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | Recomanation1 | Low fat croissant,Yupi bread          |
|  2 | Recomanation1 | Low fat croissant,Yupi bread          |
+----+---------------+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: may you show the result of your current "almost fine" query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you seem to use a relational database in a way it is not meant for. The table `recommendations` violates the condition of the so-called [first normal form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). I recommend to split it into two tables:

- `recommendations`: `id`, `name`
- `recommendationContents`: `recommendation_id`, `product_id`

And this is how your query will look like:

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, GROUP_CONCAT(p.name)
FROM recommendationContents AS rc
  JOIN recommendations AS r ON rc.recommendation_id = r.id
  JOIN products AS p ON rc.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY r.id, r.name
```

Comment: I guess that products table does not change, only recommendations table change. Right?

Comment: So then every number in `elements_to_announce` should be in one field?

Comment: But... If for example `rc.product_id` is NULL ?

Comment: If and how you want to handle this depends on how you define the business-meaning of it and if you want to allow this at all (column nullable).

Answer (score 0):

GROUP_CONCAT and FIND_IN_SET functions will be used to achieve it.

```
select r.id as id,r.name as name,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.elements_to_announce) FROM products as p
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(p.elements_to_announce, r.elements_to_announce)) as elements_to_announce from recommendations as r
```